# Matplotlib: when rotating xticks appears non-uniform gap between labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is odd. When rotating -90º all labels they appear equally spaced and located in their place:

```
feat_names = ["totalUniqueCustomerPhoneNumberLocal_f",
                "userIdentitty_f",
                "EMAIL_WEEKS_1_f",
                "length_f",
                "totalValidations_f",
                "amount_per_purchase_k",
                "amount_f"]

X1 = np.array([0.18790969, 0.18208303, 0.15003641, 0.11143482, 0.07428987,
       0.06846322, 0.06773489])

plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(X1.shape[0]), X1,color="r", align="center")
plt.xticks(range(X1.shape[0]), feat_names, rotation = -90)
plt.xlim([-1, X1.shape[0]])
plt.show()
```

[image: result of script]

However, I need them rotated -45º, and this is what happen:

```
feat_names = ["totalUniqueCustomerPhoneNumberLocal_f",
                "userIdentitty_f",
                "EMAIL_WEEKS_1_f",
                "length_f",
                "totalValidations_f",
                "amount_per_purchase_k",
                "amount_f"]

X1 = np.array([0.18790969, 0.18208303, 0.15003641, 0.11143482, 0.07428987,
       0.06846322, 0.06773489])

plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(X1.shape[0]), X1,color="r", align="center")
plt.xticks(range(X1.shape[0]), feat_names, rotation = -45)
plt.xlim([-1, X1.shape[0]])
plt.show()
```

[image: result of script2]

Any idea on how to make the labels start aligned with the center of the bar when they are rotated -45º?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal alignment is done via `horizontalalignment` or its alias `ha`,

```
plt.xticks(..., rotation = -45, ha="left")
```